# Magento2 form save not working

Tags: admin, blocks, magento2

I'm trying to save a simple phtml form with a single input field. Can't figure why clicking on 'Save' Button won't trigger a call to the save.php controller. Path seems ok, but no action is triggered. 
Code below:

> Yotpo\Yotpo\Block\Adminhtml\System\index.php:

```
namespace Yotpo\Yotpo\Block\Adminhtml\System;


class Index extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Container {

protected $_blockGroup = 'Yotpo_Yotpo';

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Yotpo\Yotpo\Block\Config $config,
    array $data = []
) {
     $this->_config = $config;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

protected function _construct()
{
   $this->_blockGroup = 'Yotpo_Yotpo';
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_Settings_index';
    parent::_construct();
}

 protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->getToolbar()->addChild(
        'save_button',
        'Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button',
        [
            'id' => 'save',
            'label' => __('Save Configuration'),
            'class' => 'save primary',
            'data_attribute' => [
                'mage-init' => [
                'button' => ['event' => 'save', 'target' => '#yotpo-form'],
                ]

            ]
        ]
    );
}

public function getFormActionUrl()
   {

    return $this->getUrl('adminhtml/settings/save');
   }

}
```

> Yotpo\Yotpo\Controller\Adminhtml\Settings\save.php:

```
namespace Yotpo\Yotpo\Controller\Adminhtml\System;

class SaveRates extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context,
        \Yotpo\Yotpo\Block\Config $config,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_config = $config;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_redirect('adminhtml/*/');
    }
}
```

> Yotpo\Yotpo\View\Adminhtml\Layout\adminhtml_settings_index.xml:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="formkey" />
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Yotpo\Yotpo\Block\Adminhtml\System\index" name="yotpo.settings" template="grid.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> Yotpo\Yotpo\View\Adminhtml\Templates\grid.phtml:

```
?>
<?php
/**
 *  @var $block \Yotpo\Yoypo\Block\Adminhtml\System\index
 */
?>
<form id="yotpo-form" action="<?php echo $block->getFormActionUrl() ?>" method="post">
    <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
    <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo $this->getFormKey(); ?>" />
    <input id="app_key" type="text" value="<?php echo $block->_config->getAppKey();?>" class="
</form>
```

clicking on 'Save Configuration' button suppose to trigger the save action. 
if I add a simple html submit button - this button triggers the desired save action:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit">
```

How can I make the Magento save button to work?

Would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description your problem is with the Magento-added save button connecting to your form. I can't comment on that. But there are other problems with the code you've provided:

Please verify you copied the right code and filenames. If so, there are some mismatches between filename and class/namespace that are probably causing your problems.

1. `Yotpo\Yotpo\Block\Adminhtml\System\index.php`: All class filenames should start with an uppercase letter, exactly matching the contained class name. This should be `Index.php`. Fix references accordingly.
2. `Yotpo\Yotpo\Controller\Adminhtml\Settings\save.php`: Again, filename capitalization. `Save.php`. There's also a complete discrepancy between that file path and your namespace and class name. Based on that path, your namespace should be: `Yotpo\Yotpo\Controller\Adminhtml\Settings`. Your class name should be: `Save`. What you have contains **System** (rather than Settings), and **SaveRates** (rather than Save).
3. Part of your form HTML is invalid or cut off. `<input id="app_key" type="text" value="<?php echo $block->_config->getAppKey();?>" class="` (line ends there)