# magento 2 get empty post array in version 2.0.5

Tags: magento2, controllers, post-data

I tried every possible thing get when I using the get method it works fine but post does not send any value.
  using this in my controller.

```
$post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
```

but got a empty array.
form content

```
$controller_path = $block->getUrl('module name/activate');
           <form method="post" id="form1" name="form1"  action="<?php echo $controller_path;?>" >
                <p><b><span style ="color:#14497f";>Please confirm your email address:</span></b>
                <input type="email" placeholder="Admin email address" style =" margin-left:5px;" size="30"  name="email" /><b>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" style ="margin-left:2px;background: #14497f none repeat scroll 0% 0%;border-color: #14497f;color: #FFF;" value="Proceed to the final step">
```

Comment: kindly add your your form code?

Comment: try this `$this->getRequest()->getPost()` or direct `$this->getRequest()->getPost('email')`

Comment: @Qaisar Satti i tried this also.

Comment: did you get values in `$_POST[]`?

Comment: @Qaisar Satti empty

Comment: @Qaisar Sattin  $_GET[] returns values  and key

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try

```
$this->getRequest()->getParams();
```

You can access specific parameter by

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam('something');
```

Post form action

```
<form id="yotpo-form" action="<?php echo $block->getFormActionUrl() ?>" method="post">
    <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
    <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo $this->getFormKey(); ?>" />
    <input id="app_key" type="text" value="<?php echo $block->_config->getAppKey();?>" class="
</form>
```

Inside your Block

```
public function getFormActionUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('feedback/index/post', ['_secure' => true]);
}
```

Make sure your Back end controller extend `Magento\Backend\App\Action`
I tested in my controller, those are working fine. if not working there is something went wrong in posting.

Fell free to share your code if not working, hope this helps.

Comment: i tried this but got nothing .. and i am working in backend so extends Magento\Backend\App\Action; this

Comment: i check this also it work good

Comment: okay i can try this one

Comment: I think you missed Form key, Please try to go with my updated answer. and check this reference link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90382/magento2-form-save-not-working

Comment: thanks it works you are right form-key is missing i add the form key then it works :)

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same problem ago

I got blank array in post due to some misconfiguration of .htaccess rule

I will suggest you changed your .htaccess with fresh one

may be it helpful to you